# Complement of "attentive" in the sense of "vigilant"

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

In several dictionaries I have found that "attentive" can mean either "paying attention", "observant", "vigilant", etc, or "courteous", "considerate (about)", "careful to fulfil the needs (of)".

With the second meaning, "attentive" is often followed by "to", which apparently is never the case for the first meaning of "attentive". For example:

- The students in Mr. Graham's English class were **attentive**.
- She was always **attentive to** his needs.

Is there a way to specify who or what is the receiver of the attention in the first meaning of **attentive**?

In the above example, it is implied by context that the students pay attention to Mr. Graham, but how can one say "The cat is paying attention to the bird's movements" using the word **attentive**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: By simply inserting the word into the sentence!

"The cat is **attentive** to the bird's movements" is a grammatically correct sentence which clearly defines what is receiving attention.

In the Mrs. Graham's English class example, without specifically stating what the kids were paying attention to, they were simply generally not tuning out during Mrs. Graham's lessons. If you want the reader to know for a certainly to what they were being attentive, you simply need to state it:

"The students in Mr. Graham's English class were attentive to the shockingly foul curse words her gnarled hand was scrawling on the blackboard," for example...   :-)

But without specifically stating what the focus of the person's attention is, the meaning in the sentence as you stated it would simply be that the kids are "not daydreaming."

Comment: Yes. *Attentive* is an intransitive verb which can take an indirect object, though it is perfectly possible in general terms simply to *be attentive* (by implication, to that which is going on around you).

Comment: The problem I see in doing this is that you get **attentive to**, which means "courteous", "considerate" and so on. Probably the reason behind the cat paying attention to the movements of the bird is to find the right moment to jump on the bird, not to be courteous.

Comment: Octania, just because the phrase becomes "attentive 'to'" doesn't mean the definition becomes 'courteous.' It can (and does, in this case) still mean 'paying attention to.'

Comment: @Octania You are right in so far as there are two different senses in which *attentive* is used, and this is borne out by the OED. Sense 1a *Steadily applying one's mind, observant faculties, or energies; giving or evincing careful consideration; intent, heedful, observant.* sense 2. *Assiduous in ministering to the comfort or pleasure of others, giving watchful heed to their wishes; polite, courteous*. In the case of the cat and the bird it has to be sense 1a. It cannot be 2.

Comment: @M. Z. I haven't seen any example with "attentive to" in the sense of 'paying attention' in the dictionaries. I asked because "attentive" seemed a bit like "vigilant", being alert in a general sense, but not focusing on something specific

Comment: @Octania The OED carries a number of examples from Chaucer to the 19th century. In the following group the one from 1711 clearly fits the idea of being attentive specifically to something.1622 *T.Scott Belgicke Pismire 41Diligent and attentiue at their workes.* 1711  * J. Addison Spectator No. 3.The News..to which she was exceedingly attentive.* 1867 *G. MacDonald Ann. Quiet Neighbourhood I. viii. 224   A more attentive and devout worshipper was not in the congregation*. **It is also perfectly idiomatic nowadays - *please be attentive to the speaker's words***.

Comment: I agree, @Octania: if there is no modifying prepositional phrase, no "to xxx," that is exactly what 'attentive' means: giving attention particles outward, rather than being preoccupied internally. I agree with you 100 percent.

Comment: I was probably looking for something like this: in the definition of *thorough* in WordReference, one of the entries says *being very attentive to accuracy and detail*